# Error using Style Generator with AppCompat

Tags: android, styles, themes

I have used a [Style Generator](http://jgilfelt.github.io/android-actionbarstylegenerator/#name=example&compat=holo&theme=light&actionbarstyle=solid&texture=0&hairline=0&neutralPressed=1&backColor=E4E4E4%2C100&secondaryColor=D6D6D6%2C100&tabColor=33B5E5%2C100&tertiaryColor=F2F2F2%2C100&accentColor=33B5E5%2C100&cabBackColor=FFFFFF%2C100&cabHighlightColor=33B5E5%2C100) to increment my App Style. But I have a problem when I generate a style for AppCompat.

The error:

```html
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102ce
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102d7
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102db
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f3
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x010102f7
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010300
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x01010397
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039c
11-29 05:25:04.637: E/ResourceType(27454): Style contains key with bad entry: 0x0101039d
11-29 05:25:04.667: E/AndroidRuntime(27454): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
11-29 05:25:04.667: E/AndroidRuntime(27454): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{br.com.pixells.simuladorbr/br.com.pixells.simuladorbr.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalStateException: You need to use a Theme.AppCompat theme (or descendant) with this activity.
```

I only generated the style, I copied all folders to my "res folder" and change the theme in manifest like this:

```html
android:theme="@style/Theme.Abar" >
```

The style generated is:

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>

    <style name="Theme.Abar" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.DarkActionBar">
        <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_abar</item>
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_abar</item>
        <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Abar</item>
        
                <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
        <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Abar.Widget</item>

    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Solid.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Light.ActionBar.Solid.Inverse">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_solid_abar</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundStacked">@drawable/ab_stacked_solid_abar</item>
        <item name="android:backgroundSplit">@drawable/ab_bottom_solid_abar</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Abar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBar.Transparent.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/ab_transparent_abar</item>
        <item name="android:progressBarStyle">@style/ProgressBar.Abar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="PopupMenu.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListPopupWindow">
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_abar</item> 
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownListView.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ListView.DropDown">
        <item name="android:listSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_abar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="ActionBarTabStyle.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionBar.TabView">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/tab_indicator_ab_abar</item>
    </style>

    <style name="DropDownNav.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.Spinner">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/spinner_background_ab_abar</item>
        <item name="android:popupBackground">@drawable/menu_dropdown_panel_abar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownSelector">@drawable/selectable_background_abar</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="ProgressBar.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ProgressBar.Horizontal">
        <item name="android:progressDrawable">@drawable/progress_horizontal_abar</item>
    </style>
    
    <style name="ActionButton.CloseMode.Abar" parent="@android:style/Widget.Holo.ActionButton.CloseMode">
        <item name="android:background">@drawable/btn_cab_done_abar</item>
    </style>

    <!-- this style is only referenced in a Light.DarkActionBar based theme -->
    <style name="Theme.Abar.Widget" parent="@android:style/Theme.Holo">
        <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Abar</item>
        <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Abar</item>
    </style>

</resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this in your code.
change "parent" attribute value.

```
<style name="Theme.Abar" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">
    <item name="android:actionBarItemBackground">@drawable/selectable_background_abar</item>
    <item name="android:popupMenuStyle">@style/PopupMenu.Abar</item>
    <item name="android:dropDownListViewStyle">@style/DropDownListView.Abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarTabStyle">@style/ActionBarTabStyle.Abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionDropDownStyle">@style/DropDownNav.Abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionBarStyle">@style/ActionBar.Solid.Abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeBackground">@drawable/cab_background_top_abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeSplitBackground">@drawable/cab_background_bottom_abar</item>
    <item name="android:actionModeCloseButtonStyle">@style/ActionButton.CloseMode.Abar</item>

            <!-- Light.DarkActionBar specific -->
    <item name="android:actionBarWidgetTheme">@style/Theme.Abar.Widget</item>

</style>
```

Comment: Don't help, because if i change the field as you said, appears other errors in the xml like this:



**android:actionBarItemBackground requires API level 14 (current min is 8)**